# Swift Facebook Login: The provided access token is invalid or has expired

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, telerik, facebook-login

I am trying to register / login users to my IOS app using the facebook sdk.
when i press the login button safari opens a Facebook login screen. After correct credential are entered i am returned to the app and the log in button changes to logout button and i can retrieve user information (name and email address). the problem is when i try to pass this on to my backend services (telerik / everlive) it comes back with the following error:

```
Failed to log in the user: The provided access token is invalid or has expired
```

all the following code is from my **LoginViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        print("User is already logged in")
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center

        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        loginView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

//

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    print("Returned from Login")

    if ((error) != nil)
    {

        print(error.description)
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        print("cancelled")
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            print(result.token)
        }
        print(result.token.tokenString)
        print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

        fbToken = result.token

        registerUserFromFacebook()

    }
}
```

//

```
func registerUserFromFacebook(){
    print("1")

    print(fbToken.tokenString)
    EVUser.loginWithFacebook(fbToken.tokenString , block: { (user:EVUser!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            user.username = String("\(self.facebookFirstName)\(self.facebookLastName)")

        } else {
            //This is the error
            print("Failed to log in the user: " + error.domain)
        }
    })
}
```

I am struggling with this and all the documentation for both telerik and Facebook SDK are in objective c which I don't know opposed to swift.

Comment: it is not issue of facebook for sure

Comment: Im not 100% sure where the issue lies. i checked the string token just after logging in and just before sending it to telerik and they are the same @RohitKP

Comment: Are you logging out user anywhere? Try reseting your simulator and try again. It happened to me that some token was stored there and it would invalidate the others

Comment: Thanks very much @CatalinaT. was testing on an ipad. I uninstalled the app, then reinstalled it and it worked.

Comment: Great! you're welcome :)